# Value is not assigned to the input element returned by document.getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can set the value easily, below is the code:

```
    document.getElementById("set").onclick = function() {
    var d = document.getElementById("text").value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "data" : d }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.error) {
            console.log("Runtime error.");
        }
    });
    window.close();
}
```

sync.set is working fine. I want the sync.get function to work on a different domain whose input field is like this

```
<input class="valueinput" type="text" name="Text_Value" size="12" value="" onfocus="select()" maxlength="6">
```

As you can see there is no id assigned. I am not getting the stored value in the textbox above. Below is the get code I am using.

```
function get() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(items) {
        if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
            console.log(items);
            var textarea = document.getElementsByName("Text_Value");
            textarea.value = items.data;
        }
    });
}
get();
```

The input box does not have any id. Please help.

Comment: And what happens if you debug the code and set a breakpoint at `if (!chrome.runtime.error) {` and step through the code?

Comment: this comes...     items = Object {data: "heya"}

Comment: when debugging textarea.value = items.data; it shows   textarea = [input.valueinput]

Comment: `[.....]` means an array, see the answer. This is why debugging is extremely helpful when you're learning and there are lots of things you don't know yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns an array-like NodeList collection, not a single element as you can see for example when [debugging the code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) step by step.

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByName("Text_Value")[0];
if (textarea) { // always check if the element exists!
    textarea.value = items.data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. You saved me :D It works fine now. You are great. Not only you solved my problem but also introduced me to the concept of debugging which will help me later on. Thank you soooooo much. As u told, I am deleting my comments regarding debugging. If I need your help then please help again in future. :) ^_^